# Linear Interpolation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two arrays the first one represents the time axis with time stamp 1 min

```
time=[0,60,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540]
```

and the second array represents a data values as follows

```
data=[18,12,12,0,7,9,6,8,12,18,0]
```

what im trying to do is two things:

1-I would like to fix the time axis to have 1 second time stamp

2-Perform linear Interpolation as follows:

for example i have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW5bw.png)

and i would like to have sth like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaCtA.png)

In case of time repetation like the repated 60 seconds the duplication should be deleted

Comment: _"In case of time repetation like the repated 60 seconds the duplication should be deleted"_ Which duplicate should be deleted: 12 or 15? What's the correct value for time 60 and why?

Comment: First of all the 60 in the time axis will be deleted and the data value should be deleted also , i updated the question

Comment: the data should bne duplicated as well

Comment: That's two questions. First question is how to remove the duplicate and the second question is how to interpolate the data. Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Is `time` sorted?

Comment: yes it is sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove duplicates (the first value is kept) with

```
time = [0,60,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540];
data = [18,12,12,0,7,9,6,8,12,18,0];
[time_u unique_indeces] = unique(time);
data_u = data(unique_indeces);
clear unique_indeces;
```

and interpolate with

```
time_i = linspace(min(time), max(time), max(time) - min(time) + 1);
data_i = interp1(time_u, data_u, time_i);
```

I prefer `linspace` because I usually want to set the number of data points and not the space between points but you can also use `min(time):max(time)` or `time(1):time(end)` instead.

This code will also sort your data points by time.

Answer (score 1):

Function [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) does the job:

```
time=[0,60,120,180,240,300,360,420,480,540];
data=[18,15,0,7,9,6,8,12,18,0];
time_1s = 0:540;
data_interpd = interp1(time, data, time_1s);
```

Note: I have manually deleted the first duplicate value at time 60. If there is only one value to remove (always at same place), I think the best is to remove it by using a mask, since `unique` removes the second occurrence of duplicates and not first one.

Comment: _"Error using matlab.internal.math.interp1
Sample points must be unique and sorted in ascending order.

Error in interp1 (line 154)
        VqLite = matlab.internal.math.interp1(X,V,method,method,Xqcol);"_

Comment: **This throws an error**, please test your code before posting it as an answer

Comment: Due to duplicate value for a specific time. I remove the duplicate value according to the comment of @JohnK (first of 60).